# Dynamic Class Binding SVG in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, svg

The following uses the array syntax for binding static and dynamic classes in one go. The static works, but the dynamic doesn't.

How does dynamic class binding work with SVG?

https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-class-binding-svg-in-vue-js-jc5qg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <style>
      .static {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1;
        fill: yellow;
      }

      .dynamic {
        fill: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <svg id="app" width="100%" height="100%">
      <circle
        cx="50" cy="50" r="40"
        :class="[ 'static', dynamicToggle ? 'dynamic' : '' ]"
      />
    </svg>

    <button
      @click.prevent="dynamicToggle = ! dynamicToggle"
      >toggle color
    </button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          dynamicToggle: false
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `button` is not in the vue app.

You can wrap it in another div to fix this :

```html
    <div id="app">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%">
        <circle
          cx="50"
          cy="50"
          r="40"
          :class="[ 'static', dynamicToggle ? 'dynamic' : '' ]"
        />
      </svg>
      <button @click.prevent="dynamicToggle = ! dynamicToggle">
        toggle color
      </button>
    </div>
```